# Where is java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.java?

Tags: java, cryptography, java-17

I'm trying to debug a strange scenario, where recovering an ECDSA private key fails from time to time.

The EC private key is stored in a persistent secure storage and is recovered/reconstructed on request. Sometimes during higher load, one of the requests fails (while the others are successful), with an unexpected exception:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : null
        at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(ECKeyFactory.java:170)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:383)
...
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : null
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(PKCS8Key.java:135)
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.<init>(PKCS8Key.java:95)
        at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl.<init>(ECPrivateKeyImpl.java:75)
        at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECKeyFactory.implGeneratePrivate(ECKeyFactory.java:245)
        at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(ECKeyFactory.java:166)
```

The code behind this is:

```java
KeyFactory ecdsaKeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
...
byte[] decodedPrivateKey = ...; // get from secure storage
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec recoveredPrivateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decodedPrivateKey);
return (ECPrivateKey) ecdsaKeyFactory.generatePrivate(recoveredPrivateKeySpec);
```

This is on OpenJDK 17 (build 17.0.6+10-Debian-1deb11u1). Trying to figure out what is going on here, I'm looking for the source code. I can find [`sun.security.ec.ECKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/jdk-17+6/src/jdk.crypto.ec/share/classes/sun/security/ec/ECKeyFactory.java#L162) (even though the lines don't match the stacktrace), but I cannot find `java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.java`.

Comment: on [Github](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-17%2B10/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/pkcs/PKCS8Key.java) ?! or `JAVA_HOME/lib/src.zip` in `java.base/sun/security/pkcs` !?

Comment: As it happens only under heavy load: are you sure your `get from secure storage` part is 100% thread-safe? May be the returned key data is incomplete? Before creating the PKCS8EncodedKeySpec you could log the hash of the key data just to make sure...

Comment: You're right on the money there, @Robert ... I just found a shared instance of `javax.crypto.Cipher` ... #facepalm.